# Problem when one store adds date and time also changes to all other stores

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a problem in the php panel when I try to add delivery date of a product it also changes in all other users, I do not know if it is error in the database or php, I will leave below some references of the extruturas.

File: Time_model.php

```html
<?php
class Time_model extends CI_Model{
        function get_time_slot(){
           $q = $this->db->query("Select * from time_slots limit 1");
            return $q->row();
        }
        
        function get_closing_date($date,$store_id){
           $q = $this->db->query("Select * from closing_hours WHERE store_id=".$store_id." AND date >= '".date("Y-m-d",strtotime($date))."'");
            return $q->result(); 
        }
        function get_closing_hours($date){
           $q = $this->db->query("Select * from closing_hours where date = '".date("Y-m-d",strtotime($date))."'");
            return $q->result(); 
        }
}
?>
```

File: Admin.php

```html
public function time_slot(){
        if(_is_user_login($this)){
                $this->load->model("time_model");
                $timeslot = $this->time_model->get_time_slot();
                
                $this->load->library('form_validation');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('opening_time', 'Opening Hour', 'trim|required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('closing_time', 'Closing Hour', 'trim|required');
                if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
          {
            if($this->form_validation->error_string()!="")
             $this->session->set_flashdata("message", '<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                                        <i class="fa fa-warning"></i>
                                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                                      <strong>Warning!</strong> '.$this->form_validation->error_string().'
                                    </div>');
          }
          else
          {
            if(empty($timeslot)){
                    $q = $this->db->query("Insert into time_slots(opening_time,closing_time,time_slot) values('".date("H:i:s",strtotime($this->input->post('opening_time')))."','".date("H:i:s",strtotime($this->input->post('closing_time')))."','".$this->input->post('interval')."')");
                  }else{
                    $q = $this->db->query("Update time_slots set opening_time = '".date("H:i:s",strtotime($this->input->post('opening_time')))."' ,closing_time = '".date("H:i:s",strtotime($this->input->post('closing_time')))."',time_slot = '".$this->input->post('interval')."' ");
                  }  
                }            
            
            $timeslot = $this->time_model->get_time_slot();
            $this->load->view("admin/timeslot/editm",array("schedule"=>$timeslot));
        }
        else
        {
            redirect("admin");
```

Table Structure:

```html
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `time_slots`
--

CREATE TABLE `time_slots` (
  `opening_time` time NOT NULL,
  `closing_time` time NOT NULL,
  `time_slot` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `store_id` varchar(500) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `time_slots`
--

INSERT INTO `time_slots` (`opening_time`, `closing_time`, `time_slot`, `store_id`) VALUES
('05:02:00', '12:00:00', 60, '319'),
('05:02:00', '12:00:00', 60, '320'),
('05:02:00', '12:00:00', 60, '321');
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Please help me, I am trying to solve this for days, but I don't have a lot of knowledge.

Comment: I was a little confused with your question and the code. In the question you mentioned "delivery date", "user"...but your Table code only has "time_slots". Anyway, sounds like you are missing is a `WHERE user="variable_here"` condition in your SQL that will update/insert records only for that user.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: Hello Bruno. So it's a product input script, but this area is where the customer marks the product data and delivery time and, unfortunately, is trying to add the data and product delivery time, the user adds the values ​​for all other users, and I would like the file to be just for each user, hope you understand, thanks for the help.

Comment: @Maykon I'm only seeing code relating to opening/closing times, nothing to do with delivery time. Maybe something was lost in translation, but it might help if you could give an example of a generated query. Also, what exactly do you mean by "changed in all users"? I'm not sure if you want each user to be able to see only things they've entered, or if it's actually changing data that was entered by other users.

Comment: @donutguy640 Hello, yes it is date and time, I would like each store to register its time, but in this code, if a store records a date and time this change in all other stores, then I would just like each store to register its date. and time without affecting the others.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add store_id to both statements. Namely, the column list in the INSERT statement, and as part of a WHERE clause in the UPDATE statement. Currently, since the UPDATE statement doesn't have a WHERE clause, it applies the change all records.

I found some extra quotes I accidentally added at the end of both statements. If you copied and pasted my code, that might have been why it didn't work. Sorry about that! I've spent the last 15 minutes staring at it trying to see what else I may have missed.

File: Admin.php

```
else
{
    if(empty($timeslot)){
        $q = $this->db->query(
        "Insert into time_slots(opening_time,closing_time,time_slot, store_id) values(
        '" . date("H:i:s",strtotime($this->input->post('opening_time'))) . "',
        '" . date("H:i:s",strtotime($this->input->post('closing_time'))) . "',
        '" . $this->input->post('interval') . "',
        " . $this->input->post('store_id') . ")");
    }else{
        $q = $this->db->query("
        Update time_slots set 
        opening_time = '" . date("H:i:s",strtotime($this->input->post('opening_time'))) . "',
        closing_time = '" . date("H:i:s",strtotime($this->input->post('closing_time'))) . "',
        time_slot = '" . $this->input->post('interval') . "',
        WHERE store_id = " . $this->input->post('store_id'));
    }
}
```

DISCLAIMER: I have not yet answered many questions here, nor figured out how to implement given code on my own machine for testing. But, looking at what you've given, I really think this is at least part of your problem, if not all.

Comment: If so, what would this code look like, could you help me?

Comment: I don't think I have enough information to even approach something you can copy and paste, but I have in mind something like what you have in Time_model.php - 'WHERE store_id=".$store_id'...I don't see where you call time_slot() and don't know where else store_id might be stored. If you add such code to your question, I might be able to.

Comment: I added to the question the excerpt that is in the file Admin.php, thanks for the help.

Comment: It looks to me like you just copy/pasted the excerpt you already had, with store_id added to the column list. That would throw an error, since you didn't also add a value to go with it. In any case, I've updated my answer based on a guess as to how the user's store_id would be accessed.

Comment: I added, did the tests, but still the same mistake, always a store when changing / recording date and time changes also for all other stores.

Comment: You added the changes I made and it still does it? The only thing left I can think of to suggest, is to create a whole second database and set of files, and paste in the code you put in your question. That should help you see it from our perspective, and may help you clarify the question. When I try to do that, I get an error, "unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC), expecting end of file"...is the excerpt part of a class definition?

Comment: Is it fixed now? If it is, and if I helped you fix it, I would appreciate it if you marked this answer as accepted. Or, if you found a different solution, feel free to put that as an answer yourself.

Comment: Hello, we are still unable to resolve this issue. I am very beginner, I have a very small level and it is difficult to understand.

Comment: I edited it again, hopefully copy/paste-able this time.

Comment: Hello friend, I added the code, but it did not solve, I realized that in the database, this table can not add or delete anything, could have problem?

Comment: Yeah, if you can't add anything, you might be getting unseen errors from the INSERTs. Try commenting out any sections that try to use an INSERT statement, as well as maybe anything afterwards that might rely on said statement having been used. For example, SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()